# Is it possible to simplify this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript so sorry I don't know very much. I have the following and I would like to make it simpler. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
if (entity == "house") {
    primaryKey = store.getItem('accountID') + "02" + "00";
    table = "Content";
}
if (entity == "street") {
    primaryKey = store.getItem('accountID') + "0000";
    table = "Content";
}
if (entity == "city") {
    var primaryKey = store.getItem('categoryID');
    table = "Reference";
}
if (entity == "location") {
    primaryKey = "0001" + store.getItem('examID');
    table = "Content";
}
```

Comment: Use a switch statment like this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it with a table driven approach and no repeated code (DRY) like this:

```
var lookupInfo = {
    house: {id: "accountID", prefix, "", suffix: "0200", table: "Content"},
    street: {id: "accountID", prefix: "", suffix: "0000", table: "Content"},
    city: {id: "categoryID", prefix: "", suffix: "", table: "Reference"},
    location: {id: "examID", prefix: "0001", suffix: "", table: "Content"}
};

var primaryKey, data = lookupInfo[entity];
if (data) {
    primaryKey = data.prefix + store.getItem(data.id) + data.suffix;
    table = data.table;
}
```

Besides minimizing the code and not repeating any code, it's also easy to add more options to the table without writing any additional code.

---

Or, the data table can be made a little more compact, though not quite as elegant (from a pure programming point of view because of the hard coded constants) this way:

```
var lookupInfo = {
    house: ["accountID", "", "0200", "Content"],
    street: ["accountID", "", "0000", "Content"],
    city: ["categoryID", "", "", "Reference"],
    location: ["examID", "0001", "", "Content"]
};

var primaryKey, data = lookupInfo[entity];
if (data) {
    primaryKey = data[1] + store.getItem(data[0]) + data[2];
    table = data[3];
}
```

Either way, you get the idea of using a lookup table for the entity and then a table driven approach for the different values for each entity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a switch statement.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

```
var primaryKey;
var table = "Content";
switch (entity) {
    case "house":
        primaryKey = store.getItem('accountID') + "0200";
        break;
    case "street":
        primaryKey = store.getItem('accountID') + "0000";
        break;
    case "city":
        primaryKey = store.getItem('categoryID');
        table = "Reference";
        break;
    case "location":
        primaryKey = "0001" + store.getItem('examID');
        break;
    default:
        // do nothing
}
```

This is still verbose, but easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to declare primaryKey on the first row? I thought I had read some place that javascript variables inside a block could also be seen after the block?

Comment: You can declare primaryKey inside each case statement. If you do that, just make sure you declare the variable with var (e.g. var primaryKey = ...) inside every case statement because you don't know which statement is going to instantiate the variable. By declaring it outside the switch statement, you only have to declare the variable in one place.